# MembershipProvider user id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-membership

Greetings, 
I wrote a custom MembershipProvider for my asp.net mvc application. I get the user as follows:

```
public override MembershipUser GetUser(string username, bool userIsOnline)
    {
        using (CPersistanceManager pm = new CPersistanceManager())
        {
            pm.EnsureConnectionOpen();
            MembershipUser membershipUser = null;
            COperator oper = pm.OperatorRepository.Get(username);
            membershipUser = new MembershipUser(ApplicationName,
                                               oper.Username,
                                               oper.ROWGUID,
                                               oper.Email,
                                               string.Empty,
                                               string.Empty,
                                               oper.IsActive,
                                               false,
                                               DateTime.Today,
                                               DateTime.Today,
                                               DateTime.Today,
                                               DateTime.Today,
                                               DateTime.Today
                                                );
            return membershipUser;
        }
    }
```

how can I then retrieve logged user id (rowguid) in any controller?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like the following:

```
var userIdentity = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity;
var user = GetUser(userIdentity.Name, userIdentity.IsAuthenticated);
```

Now, you can do whatever you want with the `user` object

Comment: You can save the user objetc in session or keep it in the HttpContext for the request.

Comment: doesn't make much sense to sometimes using Username as id and sometimes Rowguid. Better decide on which one you want to use as an user identifier.

Comment: well.. I would like to always use ROWGUID